# Using file_get_contents() php file do not get executed when placed in a directory only root?

Tags: php, url, file-get-contents

Using file_get_contents($filePath) to get php file executed via Url
is working fine as long as the php file - $sassConfigName - is in the root

**question:**
if the file is in a directory, how can i use the file the same way in the url?

working example:

$sassConfigName = 'sassconfig.php'; *// sassconfig.php is in the root*

$filePath = 'http://bootstrap4.dev/'.**$sassConfigName**.'/main.scss';

```
file_get_contents($filePath);
```

Not working  example:

$sassConfigName = './config/sassconfig.php'; // sassconfig.php is in directory config. But now wrong parameters in Url.
    $filePath = 'http://bootstrap4.dev/'.$sassConfigName.'/main.scss';

```
file_get_contents($filePath);

Regards
```

Comment: `$sassConfigName = './config/sassconfig.php';` 
try `$sassConfigName = 'config/sassconfig.php';`

Comment: Problem is the php file get executed and that string get config/ as part of the parameter which is not working

Comment: Of cause there is the possibility to use the  include_path parameter. Set this parameter to '1' then a search for the file in the include_path (in php.ini) will be done. I rather did not want to use include_path and not do any editing in the php.ini!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$sassConfigName="/php/";
$filePath='http://www.w3schools.com'.$sassConfigName.'func_filesystem_file_get_contents.asp';
echo file_get_contents($filePath);

?>
```

Comment: If you are thinking of "/php/" as directorie

Comment: The use of a directory  "/php/" is not valid as i can test it

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Andreas. I will improve next time for sure. @Andreas